# Google Chrome Frame Don't Work with HTML Application (.HTA)

Tags: hta, google-chrome-frame

I want to build an application that will load the web like the web browser. But I want it looks like the application or like the .exe. When I double click, it will run the app and load the web.

My goal is :

1. The app load fullscreen.
2. There is **no** toolbar, address bar, back button, next button, etc like the web browser

Now I try with .hta and I include the `<iframe>` there for show my web application at my server. But, the problem is when I open my .hta file, the google chrome frame don't load. So, the web looks so bad. I try to open with Internet Explorer. And the chrome frame is run normally.

There is some alternatives, tricks, or ways for solve my problem?
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Titanium: http://www.appcelerator.com/. It makes custom build exes from html & JS and uses webkit. There's also one called Splashkit: http://code.google.com/p/splashkit/ which is a lot lighter and open source but there's no support or documentation and only the windows binaries are available.

Answer (score 3):

Use portable Chrome v.18, it also embeds Flash Player. If you need ActiveX support (IE behavior within Chrome, very useful for FSO FileSystem Object access, and reliable audio), install Neptune for Webkit over **[there](http://www.meadroid.com/neptune/about.htm)**. Then, create a shortcut to Chrome.exe. Right-click on it > Properties, then define the Target with this logic:

```
C:\...yourpath...\GoogleChromePortable.exe --kiosk http:/ /www.yourappurl.com.
```

--kiosk allows Chrome to open in full-screen mode (equivalent to F11) automatically (Alt+F4 to close), and disabling some keyboard shortcuts, and the http:/ /www.yourappurl.com is where you define the hosted or local path URL to your app/game/website. That means, this website will automatically open in kiosk mode when that shortcut is clicked.

To get rid of the kiosk mode, you can set back the value to -k instead of --kiosk. Chrome will now open normally.

As you are using a portable version of Chrome, you can distribute the Chrome files along with your app files. This ensures that your app will always be opened with Chrome, and it gives the professional look of an .exe file, while in fact it is only a simple browser shortcut. You can also change the name of the shortcut for the one of your app, and change the shortcut's icon graphic.

Enjoy professional distribution of any HTML4/HTML5 app ;)
I personnally had the same problem, and after learning and testing a lot with Adobe Air and Titanium Appcelerator (as well as many others, like HTMLEXE, QT, etc.), I found this useful, reliable, easy and professional way to distribute my HTML4 and HTML5 games :)